# Why balls cannot move in my code in Pygame when I code 'Pong'? Can Someone help me to check my code?

Tags: python, pygame

I am a beginner in Pygame. I have coded a function for moving two balls in different direction and I follow the instructions coding it but it seems to be not working. I can draw two balls in screen but they will not move. I fixed it for almost 1 hour but no idea why balls aren't moving.

So, Can someone helps me check my code and just give me some hints. I will really appreciate anyone who helps me!

## My code shows below

```
import pygame,sys,time
from pygame.locals import *

# User define function
def ball_move(Surface,white,pos,rad,speed):
    size=Surface.get_size()
    for item in [0,1]:
        pos[item]=pos[item]+speed[item]
        if pos[item]<rad:
            speed[item]=-speed[item]
        if pos[item]+rad>size[item]:
            speed[item]=-speed[item]
    
# Open a brand-new window

pygame.init()
Screen_size = (500,400)
Title = ('Pong')
Frame_Delay = 0.01
Surface= pygame.display.set_mode(Screen_size,0,0)
pygame.display.set_caption(Title)

# Set up white color for drawing balls

white=pygame.Color('white')

# Now, we start to draw two balls

pos1=(100,200)
pos2=(400,200)
rad=10
ball1=pygame.draw.circle(Surface,white,pos1,rad,0)
ball2=pygame.draw.circle(Surface,white,pos2,rad,0)
pygame.display.update()

# Now, define speed
speed1=(2,-2)
speed2=(-2,2)

# Now, we define a loop
while ball1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            sys.exit()
            
# Now, we move the ball
ball1move=ball_move(Surface,white,pos1,rad,speed1)
ball2move=ball_move(Surface,white,pos2,rad,speed2)
pygame.draw.circle(Surface,white,pos1,rad,0,0)
pygame.draw.circle(Surface,white,pos2,rad,0,0)
surface.fill(pygame.Color('black'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of saulspatz answer is correct, part is incorrect.  You don't have to use sprites if you dont want to. `pygame.draw` is not pretty but perfectly usable.  The main problem does seem to be your understanding of what to do in your event loop.  All this should go in it:

```
while running:
    # Handdle your events
    # update your state
    # draw to your display
    pygame.display.update()
```

Also I notice in your unreachable code after the loop you are filling after your draws.  Remember whether you `fill`, `blit`, or `draw` the latest thing goes over the rest.  So for your example:

```
import pygame ,sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

# User define function
def ball_move(surface, pos, rad, speed):
    def _add(l_pos, l_speed, l_size):
        l_pos += l_speed
        if l_pos <= rad or l_pos >= l_size - rad:
            l_speed = -l_speed
        return l_pos, l_speed
    size = surface.get_size()
    pos_x, speed_x = _add(pos[0], speed[0], size[0])
    pos_y, speed_y = _add(pos[1], speed[1], size[1])
    return (pos_x, pos_y), (speed_x, speed_y)

pygame.init()
screen_size = (500, 400)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
pygame.display.set_caption('Pong')
running = True

pos1 = (100, 200)
pos2 = (400, 200)
speed1 = (2, -2)
speed2 = (-2, 2)
rad = 10

while running:
    # Handdle your events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # update your state
    pos1, speed1 = ball_move(screen, pos1, rad, speed1)
    pos2, speed2 = ball_move(screen, pos2, rad, speed2)

    # draw to your display
    screen.fill(pygame.Color('black'))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, pygame.Color('white'), pos1, rad)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, pygame.Color('white'), pos2, rad)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: This is mostly good, but there's an additional issue with the `pos` and `speed` variables being immutable tuples. That means the `ball_move` function can't change them in place.

Comment: yep, I added code for `ball_move()`.  However, if this was my code I'd use `vector` for ball `speed` and `pos` so you could just add them.  Also I'd move ball into a class.

Comment: Thanks A billion! I realized my stupid problems through your code! Really thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your code.  The most basic is that you haven't figured out how event-driven programming works.  You need to put the code that moves the balls inside your loop.

Another problem is that I don't think you want to use the `pygame.draw` module.  It's been a long time since I wrote any pygame scripts, but as I remember, this module is useful for drawing fixed objects, like the background.  A quick look at the docs seems to confirm this.

For moving objects, I think you need to look at the `pygame.sprite` module.  Even if you got this code to work, it wouldn't move the balls.  It would just draw a new ball at another position.  So you would have first two balls, then four, then eight, ... .  Sprites actually move.  Not only is the object drawn at the new position, but it's erased at the old position.  Your code don't address erasure at all.

Hope this helps.